# Grafana not showing query editing anymore after dashboard importation - Zabbix

Tags: datasource, grafana, zabbix

I need to ask a question about a Bug that is happening with my Grafana. After I imported a Dashboard from the Grafana Labs website, to be more specific it's here >>https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/5363 - Full zabbix server status.

There is a problem in Grafana, it simply doesn't allow editing any query from the panels anymore. The option disappeared as shown below. Has anyone here gone through this?

I've already tried to restart the server, update the datasource and also delete the dash that I imported:
If anyone has any suggestions/solutions, I'm all ears.

Image link here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/itnyv.png

Comment: Make sure you are on the latest Grafana and Zabbix plugin version. There were Grafana issues before https://github.com/alexanderzobnin/grafana-zabbix/issues/1358

Answer (score 0):

kind of happening the same here. There is an evident bug when editing custom scripts for a panel or a check. After working a lot on a script, I saved the Check. But when I come back, the only option is the UI query editor, which obviously does not load my custom script. And there is NO "script editor" button. It's gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which may or may not have the same cause, but I thought I would share in case it helps anyone else.

I was getting the below error in the console. I run my Grafana instance in a windows environment, but should be similar for other Operating Systems.

```
Plugin file not found open C:\\grafana-9.2.3\\data\\plugins\\alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app\\datasource-zabbix\\datasource-zabbix\\partials\\query.editor.html: The system cannot find the path specified."
```

I noticed that the directory C:\grafana-9.2.3\data\plugins\alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app\datasource-zabbix\datasource-zabbix\ did not exist, so I created the directory manually and copied the partials directory to C:\grafana-9.2.3\data\plugins\alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app\datasource-zabbix\datasource-zabbix.

Then I restarted my Grafana service and was able to see my Zabbix queries in my Grafana dashboards.